# Find maximum whole number divisor of an amount

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Here](https://gofile.io/d/WCnEda) is the spreadsheet download to work from. I'm running on Office 365.

[image: Picture of Setup]

I am trying to get the "Rate" and the "Days Billed" for each record. The amount is a function of Rate x Days Billed. The number of Days Billed max out with the total number of days in each month (i.e. November is 30 days max); these are also whole numbers.

I wrote this formula in E2:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(MOD($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH($B2,0)))))=0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH($B2,0))))),COLUMNS($E2:E2)),"")
```

In C2:

```
=MAX($E2:$R2)
```

In D2:

```
=A2/C2
```

When I drag across it spits out all the whole number divisors (Days Billed) that result in the Amount/Days Billed to also be a whole number. It is only getting me results for whole number Days Billed which also result in whole number Rates when dividing with the Amount. I want to include Rates that go to the hundredths place as well, not just whole numbers. (Rates often go to hundredths place)

For example, if the Amount is $4,832.40 in November the **Rate** should be $161.08 and the **Days Billed** should be 30 because 30 days is the max divisor of days and 161.08 is also divisible to the hundredths place.

Each amount basically has a whole number day multiplied by a rate that can be whole number or up to the hundredths place of denomination.

I may be overthinking this, but does anyone have any ideas of how to tweak my formula to achieve what I'm after? or even a better solution? It'd be ideal if I didn't have to have those helper columns either and it was encased in a single cell formula.

Thanks a ton,
spacej3di

Comment: please include the spread sheet as a text table or photo.  Most will not download a file file.

Comment: I've included a photo. Thanks.

Comment: So you just want to know the max days that will return a rate that is accurate to the 100th place without rounding?

Comment: Yes exactly with the max number of days being the total days in the month (B2)

Comment: what happens if we cannot find a whole number of days that will evenly divide the value to the 100th place?

Comment: I would return a blank as there is only at most a handful that shouldn't be divisible; in this rare case these records would be obsolete to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LARGE instead of SMALL and multiply A1 by 100 and return the max:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF(MOD($A2*100,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH($B2,0)))))=0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH($B2,0))))),1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I had to modify the formula to correct the MOD function/excel limitation. `=IFERROR(LARGE(IF(MOD(ROUND($A2*100,0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH($B2,0)))))=0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH($B2,0))))),1),"")` by putting round in the MOD everything works.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2010/problem-with-the-mod-function-in-excel/b1d6be13-7180-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5